# Using Raydium locally - Address Lookup Table fails with "Transaction address table lookup uses an invalid index"

Tags: solana-test-validator, raydium

I'm trying to use the Raydium SDK locally with solana-test-validator but transactions involving the LOOKUP_CACHE defined in the SDK fail with the message

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: invalid transaction: Transaction address table lookup uses an invalid index
```

I downloaded the Raydium Program (and other referenced programs from the Raydium SDK), and the referenced Address Lookup Table Account (2immgwYNHBbyVQKVGCEkgWpi53bLwWNRMB5G2nbgYV17) from mainnet and include all of them when launching the validator.

Generally, is it possible to run the Raydium Program locally and is it possible to fix the issue with the Lookup Address Table?